# How do I generate SQLAlchemy code from DB or draw.io diagram?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, model, entity-relationship

How do I generate SQLAlchemy models from draw.io entity relationship diagram or directly from Postgresql database?

I used [Java Code Generator](https://github.com/JanitSri/JavaCodeGenerator) which is very fantastic tool but unfortunately it only generates Java code although it's written in Python.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @johnny-john-boy [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) will do the job... Voila